# MYSQL How to create a UNIQUE constraint on two columns any combinations (in both directions)

Tags: mysql, unique, combinations

If I have mySQL table with two row, how can I make make a constraint that same value can't be on both cols to the same time and prevent creating doubles of any combinations of both columns?

For example, if I insert the following :

```
col1    col2
a       b   ok
c       a   ok
c       b   ok
c       a   not ok sure it's already in the table
a       c   not ok because it's already in the table in other combination (c a)
f       f   not ok because same value in both columns
```

Comment: Unique how? What's your programming language? Where do you get the data from? Do you want this to be done in frontend or backend?

Comment: I guess you want this to be enforced by MySQL? Also, please note that writing HTML like that does not work. Perhaps you want to edit your post?

Comment: why not ditch the html and focus on the mysql query issue

Comment: @ JanI m using mySQL and like it frontend that means checked before insertion (fail in case) if that what you mean  with fronted or backend

Comment: @ Anders well i wrote it plain text with indentation but the site make it to one line not readable as a table .. and i can't insert images for lack of reputations.. to view it correctly u just need to click "run code snippet"

Comment: @ Drew Pierce sorry didn't get what u mean.

Comment: Yes you can make it plain text, check my edit or read about how to style your question. There are buttons and even a guide in the editor.

Comment: A simple solution would be to make both columns a joint primary key and when inputting data, make sure you sort it so the lowest value is always first. It wouldn't be a database constraint but it would solve the perceived issue.

Comment: @Jan i used trigger as proposed by Darshan Patel and i an other trigger to solve case of inserting (f, f).

Comment: can some one tell me how to mark this question as solved i don't find the button.. some one helps me please it gona be good for others looking for same issue.. thank you everybody again :-)

Comment: Why don't you try that big "help" button on the top right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long time ago, I found this on net.

Lets say, you have table, named `tableName` then you have to create a primary key which includes both column.

```
create table tableName
(
    col1 int not null,
    col2 int not null,
    primary key (col1,col2)
);
```

But creating primary key does not solve your problem for checking vice versa combination. For that, you have to create a `trigger` which check uniqueness for both side.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER tableName_bi BEFORE INSERT ON tableName FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE found_count,newcol1,newcol2,dummy INT;
    SET newcol1 = NEW.col1;
    SET newcol2 = NEW.col2;
    SELECT COUNT(1) INTO found_count FROM tableName
    WHERE col1 = newcol2 AND col2 = newcol1;
    IF found_count = 1 THEN
        SELECT 1 INTO dummy FROM information_schema.tables;
    END IF;
END; $$ 
DELIMITER ;
```

Note : Change your table and column name according to yours.

Comment: thank you very much. you understand fully my issue and the proposition solves it.. i was more looking for trigger free solution that keeps the base natural (use trigger only for external constraint like matching certain patterns).. so you think i'll need a trigger too for the last case insert (f, f)